# How do I correctly move a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo on github which contains a submodule. I'd like to move the submodule to a new directory. The closest I've gotten is:

```
git submodule add --name new git://github.com/a/b new
git rm -r --cached old
git add .gitmodules new
git commit -m "move submodule from old to new"
```

This works well but prints

```
warning: unable to rmdir old: Directory not empty
```

whenever someone checkouts out my repo and had previously run `git submodule update --init`.

How can I make a commit that instructs the client's git to remove that directory?

Comment: Did you try a `git rm -r --cached old`?

Comment: With a very recent git (1.9.0), did you simply try a `git mv old new`?